# A regular expression to match a Perl expression?

Tags: regex, perl, expression

Trying to mangle Perl source code (trying to implement a macro), I wonder (I doubt it) whether there exists a *Perl regular expression* to **match one Perl expression** (or *one function parameter*, if you prefer that view of things).
The expression may be arbitrary complex, even using multiple lines.

AFAIK things like "balanced parentheses" are impossible to do with pure regular expressions. Unfortunately all the source filters (like `Filter::Simple`) seem to be based on regular expressions.

Comment: I would highly discourage using source filters in real code.  Reconsider trying to implement a macro and think about other ways to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: @yst Interesting concept: If you need A to implement B, you are saying don't implement A, but implement B. Concretely: I'm trying to implement macros using source filters. From your comment I get the impression that macros do already exist, but you are not concrete. I don't understand the down-votes, because I've searched for answers intensively before asking this question.

Comment: ah, I was assuming you were trying to implement macros to solve some particular problem.  if you are just trying to implement macros for the sake of implementing macros, go for it.  but they would suffer the same drawbacks as the source filters they depend on.

Comment: The basic problem is that of delayed evaluation: You want to put some expression inside `{` `}` to evaluate it when actually needed while still having access to all the variables referenced (a *closure*). For this kind of code translation you need to match a Perl expression.

Answer (score 0):

See [`(?&PerlExpression)` in `PPR`](http://p3rl.org/PPR#(?&PerlExpression)) and [`PPI::Statement::Expression`](http://p3rl.org/PPI::Statement::Expression) from `PPI`.

Comment: OK, I had the Core abilities in mind. Also that "regular expressions" seems to be "code type" (i.e. not real regular expressions, I guess). I couldn't see how they look from the documentation.